# managing size of collectd directory

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool, collectd

I currently have collectd running on several servers, though the size of the stored statistics is getting a bit unmanageable. I'm relatively new to collectd, though having looked through the documentation I'm uncertain of a way to rotate or limit the amount of stored statistics.

Is it possible to do such a thing? How to people manage the amount of stored statistics?

Thanks,
Matt Delves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RRD files are designed to be fixed sized. Once created, they don't grow any further, and as new data is inserted, older data is summarised.

If they are taking too much disk space, choose which stats you do not need, and stop collecting the data, and then delete the .rrd files to match.